# How to display name field only one time?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

How to display name field only one time in **controllers** because when i used below code. It display name field each time the loop is running.
Find the attach screen shot.

**Template.xml**

```
<div class="container"> 
    <t t-foreach="weather_conditions" t-as="contn">
    <center><h4><t t-esc="contn.name"/></h4></center>
    <table class="table table-bordered ">
        <tr>
          <td>Main:</td>
          <td><span t-esc="contn.main"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Temperature:</td>
          <td><span t-esc="contn.temp"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Minimum Temperature:</td>
          <td>
            <span t-esc="contn.temp_min"/> 
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Maximum Temperature:</td>
          <td>
            <span t-esc="contn.temp_max"/> 
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Humidity:</td>
          <td>
            <span t-esc="contn.humidity"/> 
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </t>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add more description so we can understand.

Comment: In above picture you can see Indore is displayed multiple times but i want Indore is display only one time at the top and rest of the information is displays as it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container"> 
    <center><h4><t t-esc="weather_conditions[0].name"/></h4></center>
    <t t-foreach="weather_conditions" t-as="contn">

    <table class="table table-bordered ">
        <tr>
          <td>Main:</td>
          <td><span t-esc="contn.main"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Temperature:</td>
          <td><span t-esc="contn.temp"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Minimum Temperature:</td>
          <td>
            <span t-esc="contn.temp_min"/> 
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Maximum Temperature:</td>
          <td>
            <span t-esc="contn.temp_max"/> 
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Humidity:</td>
          <td>
            <span t-esc="contn.humidity"/> 
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </t>
</div>
```

If your 'name' field is same in every iteration then use the above code, so it will print only one time.

Comment: Can you tell me if 'name' field is in another class then how it work. @Bhoomi